# hwinfo --framebuffer shows nothing, can't change grub resolution

Tags: linux, fedora, grub2, display, framebuffer

I am using a Lenovo Yoga C940 15" with Fedora 34. It has a 4K screen with an nvidia gtx1650 mobile card and integrated intel graphics. I wanted to change the resolution of the GRUB menu because it is tiny in the native 4K resolution, and I tried editing `/etc/default/grub` and changing the `GRUB_GFXMODE` to something like 1920x1080, then generating the grub config and updating grub, but nothing seems to work.

I installed hwinfo so that I could see the resolutions supported by the framebuffer, but when I run `hwinfo --framebuffer`, no output appears. Redirecting it to a log file using `--log` with `hwinfo` gives a large text file but absolutely no information about display resolutions supported. What is going on here? Does my laptop hardware not support the framebuffer for some reason? When using `dmesg | grep -i 'frame.*buffer'`, I get the following output:

`[    1.770472] efifb: framebuffer at 0x4000000000, using 32400k, total 32400k [    1.770513] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device [    3.880879] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device [    5.260159] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Reducing the compressed framebuffer size. This may lead to less power savings than a non-reduced-size. Try to increase stolen memory size if available in BIOS.`

which indicates that a framebuffer is supported. What I don't understand is why I can't seem to change the resolution of the GRUB bootloader and why hwinfo doesn't display any resolution information about the framebuffer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do any of [these hints](https://linuxhint.com/set_screen_resolution_linux_kernel_boot/) help?